# XPath, return all elements with particular element inside

Tags: xml, xpath

This is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<bookstore>

<book>
  <title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>
  <price>29.99</price>
  <discount>3%</discount>
</book>

<book>
  <title lang="eng">Learning XML</title>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

I can't figure out the XPath expression which return all the books sold with discount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a book anywhere that has a discount:

```
//book[discount]
```

Comment: But this form does not implies that discount is an attribute?

Comment: Your sample data don't show a discount attribute. Please, update the specification if you want to get a better answer.

Comment: Maybe I find the solution, if it is an attribute I put @ first. Is it correct?

Comment: @Tres: Basically, yes. The exact XPath expression depends on where the attribute is.